# HAProxy & Consul-template : retry request when scaling down

Tags: haproxy, consul, consul-template

I'am working on a microservice architecture based on Docker, registrator, consul and HAProxy.

I'am also using Consul-template to dynamically generate the HAProxy config file. Everything works fine : When I add multiple instances of the same microservice, the HAProxy configuration is updated immediately and requests are dispatched correctly using a round robin strategy.

My problem occurs when I remove some instances (scale down). If a container is shut down while a request is running I have an error.

I'am new to HAProxy so is there a way to configure HAProxy to tell it to retry a failing request to another endpoint if a container disappears?

Precision : I'am using a layer7 routing mode (mode http) for my frontends and backends. Here is a little sample of my consul-template file :

```
backend hello-backend
    balance roundrobin
    mode http
    {{range service "HelloWorld" }}server {{.Node}} {{.Address}}:{{.Port}} check
    {{end}}

    # Path stripping
    reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ /hello/(.*) \1\ /\2

frontend http
    bind *:8080
    mode http

    acl url_hello path_beg /hello
    use_backend hello-backend if url_hello
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't possible for HAProxy to resend a request that has already been sent to a backend.

Here's a forum post from Willy, the creator.

> redispatch only happens when the request is still in haproxy. Once it has been sent, it is cannot be performed. It must not be performed either for non idempotent requests, because there is no way to know whether some processing has begun on the server before it died and returned an RST.
>
> http://haproxy.formilux.narkive.com/nGKXq6WU/problems-with-haproxy-down-servers-and-503-errors

The post is quite old but it's still applicable based on more recent discussions.  If a request is larger than `tune.bufsize`  (default is around 16KB iirc) then HAProxy hasn't even retained the entire request in memory at the point an error occurs.

Both fortunately (for the craft) and unfortunately (for purposes of real-world utility), Willy has always insisted on correct behavior by HAProxy, and he is indeed correct that it is inappropriate to retry non-idempotent requests once they have been sent to a back-end server, because there are certainly cases where this would result in duplicate processing.

For `GET` requests which, by definition, should be idempotent (a `GET` request must be repeatable without consequence, otherwise it should not have been designed to use `GET` -- it should have been `POST` or another verb) there's a viable argument that resending to a different back-end would be a legitimate course of action, but this also is not currently supported.

Varnish, by contrast, [does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35470333/1695906) support a do-over, which I have used (behind HAProxy) with success on `GET` requests where I have on-line and near-line storage for the same object namespace.  Old, "unpopular" files are migrated to near-line (slower, cheaper) storage, but all requests are sent to on-line storage, with the retry destination of near-line if on-line returns a 404.  But, I've never tried this with requests other than `GET`.

Ideally, your solution would be for your back-ends to be declared unhealthy, perhaps by deliberately failing their HTTP health checks for a draining time before shutting down.  One fairly simple approach is for the health check to require the presence of a static file, which gets deleted from the back-end before shutdown.  Or, you can request HAProxy consider the backend to be in maintenance mode through the stats/admin UI or socket, preventing more requests from being initiated while allowing running requests to drain.

Comment: Thank you for your rapid answer^^